# Is there a way to make a vector of objects on construction via which members can be altered?

Tags: c++

I'm trying to find a way to add objects to a vector upon construction which allows for the members of the objects to be altered.

I'm familiar with using a static member vector, but these seem to lock the instance values at the initialized state, i.e:

```
class This {
    public:
        static std::vector<This> group;
        std::string name;
        This(std::string n) : name{n} {
            group.push_back(*this);
        }
};
std::vector<This> This::group;

This one("1");      // one.name == "1"
This two("2");      // two.name == "2"
This three("3");    // three.name == "3"

This::group[0].name // == "1"

one.name = "5";     // name successfully changed to "5"

This::group[0].name // == "1" however one.name == "5"
```

Comment: There is no connection between elements of your vector and created objects - one is created from another, but there is no linkage. This is why name changed on the object itself is not reflected in the vector element. You probably want to have your vector being the vector of pointers - but that opens canworm of a question about live times of those objects, so better be avoided in my mind.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you store pointers to the elements in your vector instead of copies then it'll work

```
class This {
public:
  static std::vector<This*> group;
  std::string name;
  
  explicit This(std::string n) 
    : name{std::move(n)} 
  {
    group.push_back(this);
  }
  This(This const&) = delete;
  This(This&&) = delete;
  This& operator=(This const&) = delete;
  This& operator=(This&&) = delete;
  ~This() 
  { 
    group.erase(std::remove(group.begin(), group.end(), this),
                group.end());
  }
};
```

Note that this is not thread-safe, though, so you can't create new `This` objects in one thread while accessing or deleting `This` objects in another. There might also be issues with invalidation of the indices or iterators into the vector, so as @SergeyA suggested in their comment it is better avoided.

Comment: Is this a superior method of approach to that of knacky’s below? I’m very new to C++ and theirs makes sense to me whilst I’m struggling to follow yours which has more votes.

Comment: @askman It is the same aproach, but I made sure that when a `This` object is destroyed (e.g. because it goes out of scope) then it will also be removed from the vector. I've also made sure that you can't create copies of `This` objects because I don't see a reason why you'd want to make a copy if you can access them through the static vector. In @knacky's version you can still create copies, but these copies will not end up in the vector. If you do need to make copies you'll need to manually ensure that the copy-constructor adds the new copy to the vector.

Answer (score 0):

when you call `push_back(*this)` a copy of your object is created.
So if you want your vector to be linked with the objects you've created you need to store a vector of pointer to your object :

```cpp
class This {
    public:
        static std::vector<This*> group;  //vector of pointer instead of objects
        std::string name;
        This(std::string n) : name{n} {
            group.push_back(this); //pointer instead of the pointed value
        }
};
std::vector<This> This::group;

This one("1");      // one.name == "1"
This two("2");      // two.name == "2"
This three("3");    // three.name == "3"

(*This::group[0]).name // == "1"

(*one).name = "5";     // name successfully changed to "5"

This::group[0].name    // the returned value should be "5"
```